# svg content-type for parse files is plaintext

Tags: svg, parse-platform, content-type

When I save an svg as a parse file, it will return this with a contenttype of plaintext instead of image/svg+xml.
This make it impossible to use this URL as src for an image tag.

```
//Example
var parseFile = new Parse.File('logo.svg', file, 'image/svg+xml');
parseFile.save();
```

Then, doing this does not work:

```
<img src="THE URL TO PARSE"/>
```

Is there any way around this?